# Create stored procedures and print top 10 entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to find the top 10 profitable products from a inventory table using stored procedure and print it out. The inventory table contains cost price and selling price, and I need to deduct the cost price from selling price and using that calculated answers to sort and print out the top 10 profitable products.

How can I do that?

Comment: Which dbms product are you using? (Both stored procedures and top 10 are too often not ANSI SQL compliant...)

Comment: im using ms sql server 2012

Comment: Yes, mssql is top 10,and mysql is limit 10.

Comment: @HelloNewWorld, what do Sybase, Oracle, DB2, Informix, sqlite etc have?

Answer (score 3):

```
MSSQL                    : SELECT TOP 10 * column FROM table;

MySQL/PostgreSQL/Sqlite  : SELECT column FROM table LIMIT 10;

Oracle                   : SELECT column FROM table WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;

Sybase                   : SET rowcount 10;SELECT column FROM table;

DB2                      : SELECT column FROM table FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;

Informix                 : SELECT FIRST 10 * FROM table;
```

Comment: How can i select top 10 * based on the calculated column or rather the selling price - cost price?

Comment: Nice work! Newer Oracle versions also support ANSI SQL's FETCH FIRST!

Comment: Also, if you have  `TOP 10`, you should **always** have an `ORDER BY`, too - otherwise your `TOP` clause is really pointless - `TOP 10` ordered by what???

Comment: i want to show top 10 of the most profitable product after i've get the calculation from sellingprice-costprice

Comment: Maybe you want is this:`SELECT TOP 10 * Product,(Sell-Cost)AS ProPrice
FROM Inventory
ORDER BY (Sell-Cost) DESC
`

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL - I hope, It may work. It will display top 10 profit products. You can just add this query in procedure and call the procedure where you want.

```
SELECT Top 10 * FROM
(
SELECT (sellingprice-costprice) AS difference
FROM inventory
) difference_data
ORDER BY difference Desc
```